# FileNotFoundException exception for Java class which is present inside jar which is present in classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, classpath

I am exploring this project https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue. I added the dependencies specified in the documentation -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sonus21</groupId>
            <artifactId>rqueue-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

And added the following code -

```
@RestController
public class PaymentController {

    private RqueueMessageSender rqueueMessageSender;

    private PaymentService paymentService;

    @Autowired
    public PaymentController(PaymentService paymentService, RqueueMessageSender rqueueMessageSender){

        this.paymentService = paymentService;
        this.rqueueMessageSender = rqueueMessageSender;
    }


@PostMapping("/payment")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> payment(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody List<TransferRequestDTO> transferRequestDTOs) {

rqueueMessageSender.enqueueIn("scheduled-pay", transferRequestDTOs, 30*1000L);


..
```

Following is what I am getting in the application log -

```
SE/spring-security-config-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, 

file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository/com/github/sonus21/rqueue-spring-boot-starter/2.0.1-RELEASE/rqueue-spring-boot-starter-2.0.1-RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository/com/github/sonus21/rqueue/2.0.1-RELEASE/rqueue-2.0.1-RELEASE.jar,...]

2020-06-27 22:19:33:598 [main][] TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader[line:97] [] - Loaded [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter] names: [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter]
2020-06-27 22:19:33:599 [main][] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication[line:833] [] - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.payumoney.thirdparty.bank.bankingservices.BankingServicesApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class  com.github.sonus21.rqueue.spring.boot.RqueueMetricsAutoConfig
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:556) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at com.project.main(Application.java:19) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class  com.github.sonus21.rqueue.spring.boot.RqueueMetricsAutoConfig
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:215) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationValue(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.readBefore(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:151) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClasses.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.sort(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:232) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:98) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:547) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ com/github/sonus21/rqueue/spring/boot/RqueueMetricsAutoConfig.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:211) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationValue(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.readBefore(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:151) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClasses.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.sort(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:232) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:98) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:547) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 14 more
```

You can see that the jar files are found in local maven repo, as shown in the log -

```
/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository/com/github/sonus21/rqueue-spring-boot-starter/2.0.1-RELEASE/rqueue-spring-boot-starter-2.0.1-RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository/com/github/sonus21/rqueue/2.0.1-RELEASE/rqueue-2.0.1-RELEASE.jar
```

I checked that the jar is present in the External libraries of Intellij. Also, if I expand it, I can see the RqueueMetricsAutoConfig.class file, which is not being found.

What do I check next?

Comment: Do you add EnableRqueue annotation on application config class?

Comment: Mine is a Spring boot application, on which I am trying to integrate this. The EnableRqueue step is given for Spring application. Also, I am able to run this project standalone. I am getting this issue when I try to integrate this in my project.

Comment: @SandeepanNath not sure how it went off from my radar. Comment here if you are still seeing this issue or open a ticket in Github, will check.

Comment: @sonus21 this issue occur with my project. same as SandeepanNath. It's working fine on sample project but not working on my project (Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ com/github/sonus21/rqueue/spring/boot/RqueueMetricsAutoConfig.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist)

Comment: @Nobita can you please create an issue in Github? I'll check, also please share demo app

Comment: @sonus21 maybe I saw problem. rqueue using spring boot 2.2.0 but my project using verision 2.0.6. I have down version on my sample to 2.0.6 and an error above has occurred. You can reproduce the error by setting the version as mine. Please let me know when it is checked

Comment: @Nobita hmm you're right checking why this is happening.

Comment: @sonus21 oh no, I like this library and want to use it in the project. Do you have a plan to handle this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to use this with Boot 2.0? I can provide you a custom release that will work for 2.0 but it will not produce metrics. I need to dig into details to identify why this is failing, I tried and it seems this is failing due to internal boot code change but quite not sure why that's happening. As I can see that particular file is there in jar file. @Nobita

Comment: @sonus21 I use version 2.0 because my project it working now with this version. We cant update new version right now. If possible, please support me in this matter. Thank a lot.

Comment: @Nobita can you create a ticket at GitHub, I'll make a release for you and you can test.

Comment: @Nobita ok, I've found why this is not working, but just checked code is not compatible with spring boot 2.0.x next release 2.7.0 would be the first release to support boot 2.0.x scheduled to be released next week.

Comment: @sonus21. Wow. I hope this version release ASAP cause I need handle a feature before deadline. Haha. Thank you for information./

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the spring boot auto-configuration module, it's not trimming the file name.  The fix will be released in the next couple of days. The Working version would be **2.7.0-RELEASE**

[image]